# ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant' function totalSupply() public constant returns

Tags: solidity

i am having this error, at line 50 when i try to declare constant.

here is my code

```
    pragma solidity >=0.5.12;


contract SafeMath {

    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }

    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
    }

    function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    }

    function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }
}



contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}



contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}


contract LCSTToken is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() public {
        symbol = "LCST";
        name = "LCS Token";
        decimals = 2;
        _totalSupply = 100000;
        balances[0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), 0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe, _totalSupply);
    }



    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }



    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


   
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


   
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

---------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }


    function () public payable {
        revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: For solidty v0.5 the `constant` modifier for function was deprecated, either use pure or view.